# request and button in post method

Tags: java, spring

In the post method to accept parameters "updateButton" and "reviewButton". If you register only `params = {"reviewButton"}` and click "reviewButton", the `request.getParameter ("reviewButton") == reviewButton`, and if the two parameters to register the getParameter returns null values.

How do to determine which button is pressed?

Page

```
  <form  action="update" name ="updateCourseDTO" " action='<@spring.url "/update" />' method="POST"/>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">

        <@spring.formInput "updateCourseDTO.name"   ""/>
        <@spring.showErrors  '<br>',"error" />

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Category</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <@spring.formSingleSelect "updateCourseDTO.category" listCategories "" />
          <@spring.showErrors '<br>',"error" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <@spring.formInput "updateCourseDTO.description"/>
          <@spring.showErrors "updateCourseDTO.description","error" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Links</label>
        <div class="controls">
         <@spring.formInput "updateCourseDTO.links"/>
         <@spring.showErrors "updateCourseDTO.links","error" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Minimal Subscribers</label>
        <div class="controls">

        <@spring.formInput "updateCourseDTO.minSubscribers" ""/>
        <@spring.showErrors  'updateCourseDTO.minSubscribers',"error" />
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Minimal Attende</label>
        <div class="controls">

        <@spring.formInput "updateCourseDTO.minAttendes" ""/>
        <@spring.showErrors  'updateCourseDTO.minAttendes',"error" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions" >
        <button id="updateButton" name="updateButton"   class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  >Update</button>
       <button id="reviewButton" name="reviewButton"    class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"  >Review</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/courses/{id}/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "updateButton", 
        "reviewButton" })
 public String updateCoursePost(Model model, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") Integer courseId,
        @Valid UpdateCourseDTO updateCourseDTO, BindingResult result)
        throws AddressException, Exception {

        if (request.getParameter("updateButton") != null) {}
        if (request.getParameter("reviewButton") != null) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--), the `params` are narrowing down the mapping. So, by specifying `params = { "updateButton", "reviewButton" }`, you tell Spring to map the method only if both of parameters are present in the request, which is impossible as it is impossible click two buttons at the same time. So, you either should just omit the `params` catching both buttons in the method and doing the choice inside the method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/courses/{id}/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String updateCoursePost(Model model, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") Integer courseId,
        @Valid UpdateCourseDTO updateCourseDTO, BindingResult result)
        throws AddressException, Exception
 {

        if (request.getParameter("updateButton") != null) {doUpdate(...);}
        else if (request.getParameter("reviewButton") != null) {doReview(...);}
        else {WHAAAT?!}
 }
```

or, as I would prefer, do two different methods:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/courses/{id}/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"updateButton"})
 public String updateCoursePost(Model model, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") Integer courseId,
        @Valid UpdateCourseDTO updateCourseDTO, BindingResult result)
        throws AddressException, Exception
 {
           doUpdate(...);
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/courses/{id}/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"reviewButton"})
 public String reviewCoursePost(Model model, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") Integer courseId,
        @Valid UpdateCourseDTO updateCourseDTO, BindingResult result)
        throws AddressException, Exception
 {
           doReview(...);
 }
```